# Saving return value of subprocess.Popen to a global variable

Tags: python, subprocess

Is it possible to save or store the return value of a subprocess.Popen() to a global variable?  For example,

```
global_var = none
 ...
 def some_function():
    p = subprocess.Popen(...,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    global_var = p

 def some_function_2():
    x = global_var.stdout
```

Something like this.  I'm essentially trying to read output from a subprocess that is started earlier in code but I need to begin the read later on.

Comment: what happens when you do this? what do you expect to happen? Comparing actual behavior to expected behavior is crucial in determining how others can help.

Comment: There is nothing special about global variables.  Any variable declared at the outermost level of indentation is global.  If you simply write `p = subprocess.Popen(...)`, outside of any function or class definition, p will be a global variable.  So the Popen object, like any other, can be stored anywhere.

Comment: @JacobIRR, so performing x = global_var.stdout does not work since the value of global_var.stdout is None for whatever reason and not the file object returned from subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score 2):

So this ended up being a silly oversight.  All I needed to do was call global and the global variable name inside the function to set its value correctly like so:

```
global_var = none
 ...
 def some_function():
    p = subprocess.Popen(...,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    global global_var
    global_var = p

 def some_function_2():
    x = global_var.stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one line to `some_function`.  I also give a better solution.

```
 global_var = None  
 ...
 def some_function():
    global global_var # without this line, Python will create a local named global_variable
    p = subprocess.Popen(...,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    global_var = p

 def some_function_2():
    x = global_var.stdout
```

Better is:

```
 def some_function():
    # I assume this function does some other things, otherwise
    # you don't need to write a function to just call another.
    p = subprocess.Popen(...,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=
    return p

 my_process = some_function()

 def some_function_2():
    x = my_process.stdout
```